# File saved in "Downloads" directory but when we open this folder by starting activity files does not appear

Tags: android

I want to implement functionality for saving image in Downloads directory and after that offer to user to open this one in a directory (open directory in which user can find and open this image). But I've got one issue. Saving ends successfully, but when user clicks "OPEN" in snackbar and chooses app to perform this action another directory appears. It contains also "Downloads" directory as well, this Downloads directory does not contain saved images! It seems like in android we have two different "Downloads" directories.

Below is how i get path for save image:

```
private File getFileForImageSaving() {
    String filename = getImageNameFromUrl(mImageUrl) + ".png";
    File dest = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        filename);

    int index = 1;
    while (dest.exists()) {
      filename = getImageNameFromUrl(mImageUrl) + "_" + index + ".png";
      dest = new File(
          Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
          filename);
      index++;
    }

    return dest;
  }
```

This is how i run activity for view "Download" directory and open files.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(
          Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png");
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

This is how I save image. It is realy works, I've checked.
pri

```
vate void saveImageToFile() {
    File dest = getFileForImageSaving();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
          dest.createNewFile();
          out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

          Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(ArticleImageViewActivity.this)
              .load(mImageUrl)
              .asBitmap()
              .into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
              .get();

          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
          out.flush();

          Utils.showInSnackBar(
              ArticleImageViewActivity.this, getString(R.string.image_has_been_successfully_saved),
              Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG,
              onOpenImageInDirectoryListener,
              getString(R.string.open_image_in_directory));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Utils.showInSnackBar(ArticleImageViewActivity.this,
              getString(R.string.error_occurred_during_saving_image),
              Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT, null, null);
        } finally {
          if (out != null) {
            try {
              out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }

        return null;
      }

    }.execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially resolve my problem by using Intent.ACTION_VIEW instead of Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT and " */* " mime type instead of "image/png". But only partially because in this case user will be offered to choose a wide range of applications, but not only applications like filemanagers.

Answer (score 0):

use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` to scan the file after saving.  if you don't many/most galleries wont show your file.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html